# Handling multiple query parameters in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular Material Tabs and I want to save selected tab in URL using query parameters (I only have 2 tabs).
Also, when I'm on tab 1 I must have 2 query parameters, one for selected tab and a new one for another selected value (inspectionChecklistId).
My problem is that when I'm on second tab and I try to update the existing parameter (selectedTab) and in the same time to add the new one (inspectionChecklistId) because the first one is not updated.
I have to mention that I'm using a method to update the query paramters.

I'm using this method to update a query parameter:

```
updateQueryParams(name: string, value: number){
  this.router.navigate([], {
    relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
    queryParams: {
      [name]: value
    },
    queryParamsHandling: "merge"
 });
}
```

And I tried to update query parameters like that:
In constructor I called the method only once with the selected tab parameter:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRouter) {
   this.updateQueryParams('selectedTab', 0);
}
```

In the method that's called each time when the tab is changed I did something like this:

```
onSelectedIndexChanged(index: number){
  this.updateQueryParams('selectedTab', index);

  if(index === 1) {
    this.updateQueryParams('inspectionChecklistId', -1);
  } else {
    this.updateQueryParams('inspectionChecklistId', null);
  }
}
```

I also tried to change the updateQueryParams like this:

```
updateQueryParams(...queryParams) {
    this.router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
      queryParams: {
        ...queryParams
      },
      queryParamsHandling: "merge"
    });
}
```

and using the method like this:

```
  onSelectedIndexChanged(index: number) {
    if (index === 1) {
      this.updateQueryParams(
        { name: "selectedTab", value: index },
        { name: "inspectionChecklistId", value: -1 }
      );
    } else {
      this.updateQueryParams({ name: "inspectionChecklistId", value: null });
    }
  }
```

but using spread type, is wrong to add the entire array of queryParams like I did and I don't know how to add each element separately.

So that's what I want to have:

```
-tab 0 is selected (the first one) => localhost:4200/?selectedTab=0
-tab 1 is selected (the second one) => localhost:4200/?selectedTab=1&inspectionChecklistId=-1
```

But now, the selectedTab is not changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use spread types, just pass a parameter of type [Params](https://angular.io/api/router/Params):

```js
updateQueryParams(queryParams) {
    this.router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
      queryParams,
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
    });
  }
```

In your constructor, pass the params object:

```js
constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.updateQueryParams({selectedTab: 0});
}
```

When tab changes, call the function only once, passing both query parameters:

```js
onSelectedIndexChanged(index: number) {
  const inspectionChecklistId = index === 1 ? -1 : null;
  this.updateQueryParams(
    {
      selectedTab: index,
      inspectionChecklistId
    }
  );
}
```